# Word VBA: Use picture in userform and document without loading it twice

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I created a VBA project in which I ask the user to select some images

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

Afterwards, I load all the images into a userform. More specifically, I dynamically create an image control for each of them.

```
imageBox.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(i))
```

In the tag of the image control, I store the path to that image for later.

The user can then drag and drop the images on that userform to define their sort order. Then they click a button and all the images are loaded into a table in the Word document. So, in this step I access the image path again that I stored in the tag of the image control and through that I insert the image into the document.

```
imagePath = Me.imageCtrl.Tag

activeCell.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=activeCell
```

As you can imagine, this is inefficient. Because I first have to load the images into the userform and then I again load them into the Word document. Each images takes about 1 second to load and if I'm working with 50 images, then the user needs to wait a minute until they can start sorting the images in the userform and then they again need to wait a minute for the images to be inserted into the document.

Is there an easy way to copy the images from the userform into the document without having to load them again? Or do you generally have any better ideas on how to avoid loading the images twice? Also, if anybody knows why it takes so long for the pictures (~5Mb) to load and how this can be improved, that would be awesome! I don't need to integrate them in the full resolution, if that helps. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2023-05-26:**

As requested, here is the most important part of the code.

Basic file picker when user form is initialized:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim imageBox As Control, btnFinish As Control
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With fd
        .Title = "Select"
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png; *.wmf"
        .FilterIndex = 2
            If .Show = -1 Then
                numImages = .SelectedItems.Count
                'create an image control for each image that has been selected in the file dialog
                For i = 1 To numImages
                    Set imageBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1")
                    With imageBox
                        .Name = "ib" & i
                        .Tag = fd.SelectedItems(i)
                        .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
                        .Width = 100
                        .Height = 60
                        .Top = 6
                        .Left = 6 + (i - 1) * (106)
                    End With
                    imageBox.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(i))
                Next i
                Set btnFinish = Me.btnFinish
                With btnFinish
                        .Left = 6
                        .Top = 200
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Set fd = Nothing
    Me.Width = 500
    Me.Height = 500
End Sub
```

Code executed when button on userform is clicked

```
Private Sub btnFinish_Click()
    
    Const numCol As Integer = 2
    
    Dim ctrlImage As Control
    Dim imageTable As Table
    Dim activeCell As Range
    Dim activeTable As Integer, activeRow As Integer, activeCol As Integer
    Dim pageWidth As Double, pageMarginLeft As Double, pageMarginRight As Double, colWidth As Double, scaleFactor As Double
    Dim imagePath As String

    'count how many tables already exist before that position in the document to later on edit the correct table
    activeTable = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Start).Tables.Count + 1
    'add an empty table with 1 rows, 2 columns
    Set imageTable = Selection.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 1, numCol)
    imageTable.Borders.Enable = True
    imageTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    imageTable.Rows.Height = CentimetersToPoints(4)
    imageTable.LeftPadding = 0
    imageTable.RightPadding = 0
    
    For i = 1 To numImages
        imagePath = Me.Controls(ctrlImagePrefix & i).Tag
        'calculate current column number depending on total number of columns
        If (i Mod numCol) = 0 Then
            activeCol = numCol
        Else
            activeCol = i Mod numCol
        End If
        activeRow = Int(i / numCol + 0.999)
        Set activeCell = ActiveDocument.Tables(activeTable).Cell(activeRow, activeCol).Range
        activeCell.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=activeCell

        pageMarginLeft = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin
        pageMarginRight = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin
        pageWidth = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.pageWidth
        colWidth = (pageWidth - pageMarginLeft - pageMarginRight) / numCol
        scaleFactor = activeCell.InlineShapes(1).ScaleWidth * colWidth / activeCell.InlineShapes(1).Width
        activeCell.InlineShapes(1).ScaleWidth = scaleFactor
        activeCell.InlineShapes(1).ScaleHeight = scaleFactor

        If i < numImages And i Mod numCol = 0 Then
            imageTable.Rows.Add
        End If
    Next i
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Following variable needs to be definied within userform:

```
Private numImages As Integer
```

Comment: Assuming that image quality is important to you, you already have the best process. When you load images to a picture control they are converted to bitmap, likely with a lower resolution than the original. When you insert pictures into a document the original image file is stored in the document archive, along with a binary(?) representation in the xml. If that isn't good enough for your users tell them to do the whole thing without the user form.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of the Word file you want to work with? Otherwise, I would have to do it myself, which would take a lot more time and I would have to wait until I have more free time. My idea is to try it out with a **Dictionary**, so that I can just store it in the Dictionary when I first load it, and then take it out when I need to use it (e.g. to insert it into a Word Document. ). I'm just curious, why did you use Word for such a large image file (about 5M), did you know there is a size limit for Word files?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thanks for the explanations! The image quality is not so critical, as the images will be inserted in a 2-column table in the document. So, the final image size is not even half of the page and therefore, the needed resolution is way less than the original 5Mb size. Any suggestions on how to bring the bitmap from the userform into the document? Also, how would you do the drag-and-drop sorting without the userform?

Comment: @OscarSun The document contains a lot of code that I can't share. Do you only need the code part that loads the image from the file picker into the userform? As for the size: although I'm working with 5Mb pictures, I don't need the full quality of these images (see previous comment). I'm using Word, since the code is needed during the writing of a report which is done in Word. Do you have any other suggestions (e.g. sort images with Python by giving them a number and then the file picker in VBA will automatically import them in the right order?)

Comment: 1. I don't know what *the right order* you mean. What is it sorted by? I don't know Python, at most, I use C# or VBA or VB. I'll probably just focus on loading the images first. As for the sorting, I don't know how you want to sort it, and it may be beyond my current capabilities. 2. Of course Just give me the code for that part, including a simple version of the form you want to load the image into. For the part of the problem you want to solve, there is enough code and objects for me to refer to, so I don't have to reproduce them myself.

Comment: @Loeli - my comment "tell them to do the whole thing without the user form" meant: tell any complaining the user that even taking 2 minutes to process 50 images the whole process still takes less time than it would take them to do the whole thing themselves. As far as sorting images goes, if you're just dragging and dropping from file explorer you sort as you go by looking at the thumbnails.

Comment: @Loeli - image quality *is important* if you are resizing the image. Image quality only gets worse as you make the image smaller.

Comment: @OscarSun with sorting I mean the following: when the windows explorer is opened to select the images (via file picker), then the images will be inserted in the sorting order of the windows explorer. This means, they will typically be sorted by their name. You could for example also click the date column in the explorer, and then they'd be sorted by the date. But in my case, the user wants to sort it in a manual order. Therefore I created a userform with drag and drop capability, but my main problem is the loading time. I updated the question to contain the most basic code.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - if I don't find any solution to speed this up, the users would likely be ok with it, but I was hoping to somehow improve the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

When I use your code the line

```
activeCell.InlineShapes(1).ScaleWidth = scaleFactor
```

will encounter error, wouldn't you?

So I didn't continue. I have no idea how about your original code will go.

I'm sorry that as far as I know, there is no faster way than the **LoadPicture** method. (Even if I set the second and third argument to a smaller number, it won't be faster. (Read my code.) And the objects returned by the **LoadPicture** function can't be used for **InlienShape** or **Shape** initialization*(Both constructor functions or constructors accept only full filenames string as parameters.)*, so with my current ability, **it's necessary to load the picture twice**. (I have thought of loading the picture files into the **clipboard**, and then saving the information in a **Collection** or **Dictionary** for later direct paste into the table of a document, I don't know if it would be faster, but I haven't done it yet.)

Nevertheless, I still tried to optimize your code, you can test it and see: At least when reading the image files for the second time and inserting them into a Word document table, has it significantly improved the user's favorability? If not, then my answer is that it is not effective to improve the user experience now.

The main optimization is:

1. when loading pictures to the form for the first time, call the initialization procedure *UserFormInitialize* in the *Activate* event to [**repaint**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/repaint-method) the screen once for each picture inserted, so that users can see the picture loading process and will not be impatient. And in the Initialize event, only the width and height of the form are kept.
2. Using the [**Next** property of **Cell** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cell.next) to get the next cell object to be operated, instead of using many variables to calculate its position and other information, saves a lot of unnecessary calculations.

- Use **shapes** instead of **InlineShapes** to set the [**LockAspectRatio**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape.lockaspectratio) property so that there are no errors. *Actually still will be in error, when there are many images and operations about more than 40 or some count I think.*

[This is my test .docm file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vOxaDEtFASJ8WPTjNjPlcyW1amSjMwKX/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106108182093734588005&rtpof=true&sd=true). You can press F2 to show the UserForm1, which you can replace with yours.
[How to download the .docm *(the MS Word document file with VBA code)* file from Google Drive.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yVlDI8JN8U&t=53s) file from Google Drive.)

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.width = 500
    Me.height = 500
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    UserFormInitialize
End Sub



Private Sub UserFormInitialize()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim imageBox As Control, btnFinish As Control
    
'    Dim f As Scripting.File, FsO As New FileSystemObject, arr
    
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With fd
        .Title = "Select"
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png; *.wmf"
        .FilterIndex = 2
            If .show = -1 Then
                numImages = .SelectedItems.Count
                'create an image control for each image that has been selected in the file dialog
                For i = 1 To numImages
                    Set imageBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1")
                    With imageBox
                        .Name = "ib" & i
                        .Tag = fd.SelectedItems(i)
                        .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
                        .width = 100
                        .height = 60
                        .top = 6
                        .left = 6 + (i - 1) * (106)
                    End With
                    imageBox.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(i))
                    
                    Rem These two lines won't be faster more
'                    Set f = FsO.getfile(.SelectedItems(i)): arr = GetXY(f)
'                    imageBox.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(i), arr(0) / 200, arr(1) / 200)
                    
                    
                    
                    Rem Let users see the process of loading pictures, so that they don't have to wait for too long,
                    Rem    and enhance the user experience.
                    Me.Repaint
                    DoEvents
                    
                    
                Next i
                
                Set btnFinish = Me.btnFinish
                With btnFinish
                        .left = 6
                        .top = 200
                End With

            End If
        End With
    Set fd = Nothing
'    Me.width = 500
'    Me.height = 500
End Sub



Private Sub btnFinish_Click()

    Rem Just for testing your code
'    btnFinish_Click_Loeli
'    Exit Sub
    


rem If the procedure is opened with
rem        Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
rem and before it is finished restore it 
rem        ScreenUpdating = True 
rem Then the 60 pictures of about 5M can be inserted in about 10~20 seconds faster. However, during this time, the user will not know what Word is doing, and cannot be sure whether it is crashed or not. Because the screen is usually just blank.

    
    Const numCol As Integer = 2
    
    Dim ctrlImage As Control
    Dim imageTable As Table
    'Dim activeCell As Range
    
    Dim activeCell As Word.Cell, inlShp As InlineShape, aspectRatio As Double
    
    
    'Dim activeTable As Integer, activeRow As Integer, activeCol As Integer
    Dim pageWidth As Double, pageMarginLeft As Double, pageMarginRight As Double, colWidth As Double, scaleFactor As Double
    Dim imagePath As String
    
    
    Rem This will only record the restore action once, and the operation before the restore, just click the restore button once or press Ctrl+ z once. Very convenient.
    Dim ur As UndoRecord
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "InserImageIntoTable_btnFinish_Click" 'You can choose a name of your choice


    ''count how many tables already exist before that position in the document to later on edit the correct table
    'activeTable = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Start).Tables.Count + 1
    
    'add an empty table with 1 rows, 2 columns
    'Set imageTable = Selection.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 1, numCol)
    
    
    Set imageTable = Selection.Range.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 1, numCol)
'    Set imageTable = Selection.Range.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 1, numCol, , wdAutoFitWindow)
    
        pageMarginLeft = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin
        pageMarginRight = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin
        pageWidth = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.pageWidth
        colWidth = (pageWidth - pageMarginLeft - pageMarginRight) / numCol

    
    imageTable.Borders.Enable = True
    imageTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    imageTable.Rows.height = CentimetersToPoints(4)
    imageTable.LeftPadding = 0
    imageTable.RightPadding = 0
    
'    imageTable.Columns.width = colWidth
'    imageTable.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
'    imageTable.PreferredWidth = colWidth
    
    
    For i = 1 To numImages
    
    
        Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        
        imagePath = Me.Controls(ctrlImagePrefix & i).Tag
'        'calculate current column number depending on total number of columns
'        If (i Mod numCol) = 0 Then
'            activeCol = numCol
'        Else
'            activeCol = i Mod numCol
'        End If
'        activeRow = Int(i / numCol + 0.999)
'        Set activeCell = ActiveDocument.Tables(activeTable).Cell(activeRow, activeCol).Range
'        activeCell.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=activeCell

        If activeCell Is Nothing Then
            Set activeCell = imageTable.Range.Cells(1)
        Else
            Set activeCell = activeCell.Next
        End If
        
        Rem pics insert cells will auto fit the size of their cell
        Set inlShp = activeCell.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        
        With inlShp
            '.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue 'inlShp do this will be on error, and errors occur when there are too many Shapes also
            If .width > colWidth Then
                aspectRatio = colWidth / .width
                .width = colWidth
                .height = .height * aspectRatio
            End If
        End With

        Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        imageTable.Range.Document.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView inlShp.Range
        Word.Application.ScreenRefresh
        DoEvents
        
'        pageMarginLeft = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin
'        pageMarginRight = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin
'        pageWidth = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.pageWidth
'        colWidth = (pageWidth - pageMarginLeft - pageMarginRight) / numCol
'        scaleFactor = activeCell.InlineShapes(1).ScaleWidth * colWidth / activeCell.InlineShapes(1).width
'        activeCell.InlineShapes(1).ScaleWidth = scaleFactor
'        activeCell.InlineShapes(1).ScaleHeight = scaleFactor

'        If i < numImages And i Mod numCol = 0 Then
'            imageTable.Rows.Add
'        End If

        If imageTable.Range.Cells(imageTable.Range.Cells.Count).Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 And i < numImages Then imageTable.Rows.Add
        
'        'If imageTable.Range.Document.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages) Mod 2 = 0 Then
'        If i - 1 Mod (8 * 2) = 0 Then
'            Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'            'playSound 2
'            Word.Application.ScreenRefresh
'            DoEvents
'            Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'        Else
'            If Word.Application.ScreenUpdating Then Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'        End If
        
    Next i
    
'    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Unload Me
    
    
    ur.EndCustomRecord


End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Oscar, thanks for your effort on this. I know that my code might have some unnecessary calculations, but when I did some benchmark tests, the time for the calculations was negligible compared to the loading of the images. Also, with the current code, Word already updates after each image, so the active repainting doesn't seem necessary. Unfortunately, it looks like there is no way to load the images once into the clipboard and then use them for both, the userform and the document. :/ I guess my users will just have to deal with the loading times