# Why is my .LockAspectRatio=msoTrue showing as an error

Tags: excel, image

I want to load data including an image from a Userform onto an excel worksheet.  I want to specify the image width and to maintain the aspect ratio.

The line .LockASpectRatio = MsoTrue shows as an error.  Can anyone help with the syntax?

```
'Save image to Cell

    Dim FileNAme As Variant
    Dim Img As Picture

If FileNAme <> "" Then
    
     FileNAme = Me.TextBox_5
    
With ws
     Set Img = .Pictures.Insert(FileNAme)

With Img
    .Placement = xlMove
    .Width = 150
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    .Left = ws.Cells(lr, "D").Left
    .Top = ws.Cells(lr, "D").Top
           
End With

End With

End If
```

Comment: You can refer to my experience <https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341438/8249058> maybe on what kind of object we used.

Comment: You didn't use VBA? Still can't find your **LockAspectRatio** property in [**Picture** object in **.NET**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.picture.locked?view=excel-pia),either. What model do you use?

Comment: Hi Oscar  The LockAspectRatio Statement is in the 6th last line of code.  As far as I know this is VBA.

Comment: I know, but I can't find them *(Picture, Pictures, Insert...)* in the object browser（press key F2 in VBE）。Only on the object [Shape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.lockaspectratio) and ShapeRange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it should be

`.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue`

Another observation,

```
If FileNAme <> "" Then    
 FileNAme = Me.TextBox_5
```

You are checking if Textbox is not empty before you set the text box variable. Therefore `FileNAme`  would always empty.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio worked. Bruce